# Combining the two columns of stereo wav file data into a single array with alternating elements in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a stereo wav file data that I read into matlab, which looks something like this:

```
a =   
1   2   
3   4  
5   6
```

I want to change it to a single array like this one:

```
a = 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

so that the left and right channel audio data all come into a single array in an alternating pattern, in the same way it is stored in the wav file

I tried doing this

```
k=1;  
for i=1:length(data2)  
  data2_2(k) = data2(i, 1);  
  k=k+1;  
  data2_2(k) = data2(i, 2);  
  k=k+1;  
end
```

but it is very slow for my wav file which contains more than 200000 elements in a single channel. I will need to do this later for even bigger wav files.

Is there a built in function or a faster way to do this?

Comment: `a=a.'; a=a(:).'`, or in one line `a=reshape(a.',1 [prod(size(a))])`

Comment: and you can use `numel(a)` for `prod(size(a))`

Comment: Or just `[]` and let Matlab figure out size in that dimension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution using range indexing:

```
n=numel(a);
b(1:2:n)=a(:,1);
b(2:2:n)=a(:,2);
```

or simply:

```
n=numel(a);
a([1:2:n 2:2:n]) = a;
a = a(:).';
```

This is possible in Octave (not sure in MATLAB):

```
a([1:2:end 2:2:end]) = a;
a = a(:).';
```